# What Rails "compilation" do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I work with a big Rails 2.3 application (with more than 200 gems).
When I execute `script/server`, the "compilation" (I'm not sure Rails is compiling something) takes more than 1m45 ; it's very unproductive. I disabled cache_classes, action_view.cache_template_loading and action_controller.perform_caching, now "compilation" takes 45 seconds.

I logged some lines :

- the loading of initializers and config/environments take 5 seconds
- the loading of the config/routes (application has 3200 routes) takes 15 seconds

Then, the application do *something* that I can not explain (loading the models ? loading the gems ?) and it takes more than 30 seconds to have operational server.

The thing I don't understand is that in another computer with same project (seems to have same application configuration), all this "compilation" process takes 10 secs.

I do an hdd reading benchmark, everything is OK ; mysql server is OK (and Rails is not logging any mysql query).
Assets are not compiled, they are delivered "as-it".

How can I explain this difference ?

Comment: Asset compilation, perhaps? You know, JS/CSS? This can take a while. On my project recompiling the assets takes up to a minute.

Comment: Did you see the word "compilation" somewhere or this is just a word you chose to describe the slow startup?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev JS/CSS are not compiled. They are develired "as-it" (in `public` folder). I use "compilation" word for all the loading process.

Comment: @Зелёный I use `script/server` so assets are delivered by Rails itself. But it's not the problem, I only talk about running the server ; I didn't do any request.

Comment: That other machine - is it, by any chance, 3 times as powerful? So the startup takes 3 times less time compared to your machine.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the first machine with 45 seconds loading is 2 times more powerful than the second one. And have 2 times more RAM.